# How to handle a json field, which can be one of two different types?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I'm creating model classes for the [MSCOCO annotation format](https://cocodataset.org/#format-data).

There is one field in 'ObjectDetection', which can be one of two types:

```
annotation{
    "id": int, 
    "image_id": int, 
    "category_id": int, 
    "segmentation": RLE or [polygon], 
    "area": float, 
    "bbox": [x,y,width,height], 
    "iscrowd": 0 or 1,
}
```

So `segmentation` can either be a `List<List<float>>` or a `RunLenghtEncoding`, which as a class would look like this

```
public class RunLengthEncoding
{
    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public List<int>? Size { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("counts")]
    public List<int>? Counts { get; set; }
}
```

Question is, how to handle this case when converting the json? Normally I would create an abstract class and inherit my two different types from that. Selection of the correct concrete type could be done in a custom converter.

However, with this configuration, this doesn't seem to be possible. I also don't want to use `object`.

Comment: You could keep the property as a `JToken` for automatic deserialization, and then, in a second step, deserialize it to one of the two target types, depending on whether your JToken is an array or an object.

Comment: Would this work for you? 1. Parse as a JObject, 2. Get the segmentation field, 3. See if it's a JObject (RunLenghtEncoding) or a JArray (`List<List<float>>`), 4. Deserialize into appropriate type (you'll need 2 different classes). These guys did it in a similar way: https://github.com/vladkol/CustomVision.COCO/blob/master/COCOAPI/COCODatasetFactory.cs

Comment: Alternatively, if that is possible with json.net (didn't try): Create two correctly typed (but nullable) properties (SegmentationRLE and SegmentationPolygon), each with a custom converter which either fills the property, if the token has the correct type, or leaves the property as null.

Comment: @RolandDeschain You have to post the real json too, if you really need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case future readers are interested, here is how I solved it at the moment:

In my Annotation model class I have these three properties for the segmentation:

```
[JsonProperty("segmentation")]
public JToken? Segmentation { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public List<List<float>>? Polygons { get; set; }

[JsonIgnore]
public RunLengthEncoding? RLE { get; set; }
```

I then use the `OnDeserialized` callback to map the Segmentation to the correct property. In my case this is pretty easy, since according to the MSCOCO documentation RLE is used when `IsCrowd` is true, Polygons are used otherwise:

```
[OnDeserialized]
internal void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
    if (Segmentation == null)
        return;

    if(IsCrowd)
    {
        RLE = Segmentation.ToObject<RunLengthEncoding>();
    }
    else
    {
        Polygons = Segmentation.ToObject<List<List<float>>>();
    }
}
```

Thanks again to @Heinzi for the suggestion!